# What to do when ubuntu freezes completely?

Tags: freeze, bug-reporting

I had Ubuntu 14.04 and have done a clean install of 16.04. I had problems on 14.04 and on upgrade all problems were solved except ubuntu freezing.

Now it is freezing occasionally and only a force shutdown works. I have tried magic sysreq method, ctrl+alt+del, alt+f2, nothing can solve it. What should I do?

Comment: Try to look at logfile /var/log/messages if there are any interesting messages at the time where the system froze.

Comment: Have you tried switching to a tty with `ctrl+alt+n`, where n is a number from 1-6.

Comment: Is your processor one of these? [System freezes completely with Intel Bay Trail](//askubuntu.com/a/803649)

Comment: I have an intel pentium